# how to set up my background process handler

Tags: c, posix, inter-process-communicat

so I'm writing a shell that can have both foreground and background process. I have a:

```
signal(SIGCHLD, childHandler);
```

and thus I have handler:

```
void childHandler(int signum){
    int status, PID;
    PID = waitpid(-1, &signum,WNOHANG);
}
```

this handler captures both foreground and background children that change state.
My shell seems to work for foreground processes.
However, as soon as I call a background process, things don't work properly anymore... and I think it may be due to this handler.

Can anyone see if something's wrong/missing?

Comment: Although formally it's not wrong, I wonder why you use 'signum' as second argument to 'waitpid()' and not use 'status'?

Comment: I do not see anything wrong with your handler (other than what alk said). How are you sending processes to the background?